# Jquery mask for number and letter

Tags: jquery

I'd like check via jquery a string, thi string can begin by "P" or "M" and after that some number, sample P1456598, M124, P47, M798664645

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you had a look at Google yet?

> http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

That will do what you want in no time!

Answer (score 0):

Did you already check http://plugins.jquery.com/mask/ ?
Is a jquery plugin for masking inputs